# best process after drive upgrade (High Sierra APFS with FileVault encryption)

Tags: time-machine, disk-encryption, macos-highsierra, filevault, apfs

- I am running MacOS 10.13.5 with APFS format SSD and FileVault encryption.
- I need to upgrade the drive from 1/4 TB to 1/2 TB.
- I want to avoid having to reinstall all my applications and data after re-imaging the drive with High Sierra.
- I have an external drive that I have used for Time Machine backups, and it is formatted as **Mac OS Extended (Journaled)**.

The twist in the plot is the APFS encryption ala FileVault. If we don't encrypt until after the restore, then the encryption takes a loooooong time due to the nature of the process and the amount of data I have (nearly 1/4 TB). So, instead, the strategy is to enable FileVault before the restore step.

My proposed approach:

1. Back up the Mac to the external drive using Time Machine.
2. Install the new drive.
3. Image it with High Sierra.
4. Enable FileVault encryption (wait a long time for it to encrypt).
5. Restore my Time Machine backup to it from my external drive.

My questions:

1. Can I back up my old APFS drive to my non-APFS external drive?  I have been warned not to upgrade the drive to APFS, or else the TM backup data will be useless.
2. Are there any issues with restoring the unencrypted TM backup to my encrypted, APFS drive?
3. Is this the recommended approach, or is there a better way that I'm missing?
4. Is there a way to perform steps 2 through 4 prior to installing the drive into the Mac?

Comment: I've not actually done this with HS, but you ought to be able to just back up to TM, drop in the new drive, boot to Recovery & restore from TM.

Comment: The twist in the plot is the APFS encryption ala FileVault.  If we don't encrypt until after the restore, then the encryption takes a loooooooooooooooooooooooooong time due to the nature of the process and the amount of data I have (nearly 1/4 TB).  So, instead, the strategy is to enable FileVault *before* the restore step.  Hence my questions.